# What does the stability of blood test means for patient who have few pains in different parts of the body

Tags: blood, blood-tests, cbc-complete-blood-count

What does the stability of a CBC (and all related tests) means for a patient who is not suffering anything besides few ache here or there like in stomach or the back?

More generalized, if a blood test repeated 3 times in matter of 9 months, and the all values are in the normal range and nearly the same from test to test. Is there any conclusions we can extract from that, even if the patient still have few pains?

Comment: In general, having a normal CBC is a good thing, and repeated normal tests is reassuring. To know whether that says anything about your aches and pains or not, you need a doctor to review your results and interpret them for you in the setting of your medical history

Comment: What do you think about the stability of repeated test in  9 months ?

Comment: Stability generally is a good thing but no one can interpret results out of context, only a doctor who has your full picture can interpret those.  Read this: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor

Comment: The CBC might not be a useful test to figure out the specific symptoms being experienced.  The similarity in the results over time suggests that the factors being measured do not have much variability in this individual at this time.